# NTFS DataRun probably error

Tags: windows, filesystems, ntfs, ntfs-mft

I am writing a code to parse MFT of NTFS. I`m trying analyse Data Run of non residental $INDEX_ALLOCATION attrib:

11 01 2C 11 02 FE 11 00
9F 0B 21 01 DB 00 21 01
D9 00 21 01 E0 00 21 01
F6 00 21 01 10 01 00 F1

After regroup I see problem in Data Run No 3:
DataRun 1: 11 01 2C
DataRun 2: 11 02 FE
DataRun 3: 11 00 9F <- what does mean "00" ?

I tried analyse it using Active Disk Editor 3 and this software decompose it to:
DataRun 3: 11 00 9F 0B
In my opinion header of DataRun 3 ("11") mean 1 length and 1 offset so there should be 2 bytes after header, but there are 3 bytes.

Any idea?

Comment: Probably data run is sparse or/and compressed.